# Python function to check overlap between patterns

Tags: python, regex

Using Python 3, I am building a program that categorises descriptions using a dictionary of patterns.

```py
import re


class Categorizer:
    _categories = {
        "category_1": r".*foo.*",
        "category_2": r".*bar.*",
    }

    def _classify_description(self, description: str) -> str: 
        """
        Please do not pay too much attention to this method as it is not 
        relevant how it is implemented.
        """
        for category, pattern_str in self._categories.items():
            pattern = re.compile(pattern_str)
            if pattern.match(description):
                return category
        return "Unable to categorize"

    def __call__(self, description: str) -> str:
        return self._classify_description(description)
```

Now, I know with the design above (the `return` and the `loop` within the `_classify_description`) I will only get one category each time. However, I would like to be able to tell that there is **ALWAYS** going to be only one match.

The idea is that this categorisation is long and collaborative, so I would like to avoid:

- Having a single pattern that excludes other patterns - this would make the pattern hard to maintain.
- Doing the check at runtime. i.e please do not suggest to go through the entire dictionary and count number of matches. Because this will depend on a particular case.

What I would like to do is to write a fucntion (to make it a test) that checks out the patterns are not overlapping. This is, that none of the patterns is not a subpattern of any of the others.

Let's say a developer updates the `_categories` with the following:

```py
    _categories = {
        "category_1": r".*foo.*",
        "category_2": r".*bar.*",
        "category_3": r".*foobar.*", # New entry
    }
```

The test would fail because both `.*foo.*` and `.*bar.*` are included within the `.*foobar.*` pattern and so the code wouldn't be accepted.

For the solutions proposed, there's no need to write this using unittest/pytest, just a traditional function would work.

Thanks!

Comment: I've put an answer that handles your examples, and a pointer to a method for more complicated situations. If you edit your question to include more complicated examples you need to cover for your use case then we can likely try to help further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example given, it would be fairly easy:

```
for c1 in _categories:
    for c2 in _categories:
        if c1 != c2:
            if (re.match(_categories[c1], _categories[c2])):
                print(c2 + ' contains ' + c1)
```

To solve for a more complicated set of regex, I think you would need to parse the regex expressions into an AST and compare whether one tree is rooted in the other. There will be an upper-bound of complexity that you can handle in the patterns though.

Comment: hi @ricardkelly, thanks for the answer (and apologies for the delay). I think this solution may work for now because or patterns seems to be simple enough at the moment, but I'm not sure how long it will last. I will explore parsing into `AST` as you suggested should we need it in the future. Thanks !